# Updating objects in queryset computed with filter clears the query

Tags: django

I have:

```py
jobs = Job.objects.filter(detected__isnull=True).order_by('submitted')
print(f"Detected {len(jobs)} jobs")
jobs.update(detected=ms_now())
try:
    print(jobs[0].id)
except:
    print("No objects!")
```

Output:

```
Detected 865 jobs
No objects!
```

It seems like the filter is re-computed due to the update, but why does this happen?